# Custom jQuery Validation .addMethod

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a form that validates zip codes on a min/max length basis. I need to have the zip min be 5 digits for all countries EXCEPT Australia which needs to be 4. 
Here is what Im having trouble with:

```
$.validator.addMethod(
    "AusZip",
    function(value, element) {
        if ($("#Country").val("Aus") && ("#PostalCode").length < 4)) {
        return false;
    } else return true;
},
"Australian Zip Code Must Be at least 4 Digits");
```

then in the rules

```
rules: {
    PostalCode: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 5 //for all countries except AUS
        AusZip: true // for Aus
    }
}
```

Is length not the way to go?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm assuming *all* validation rules must pass, which means that your `minlength` will always fail if you have a length of 4.

Also, you're missing a `$` before `("#PostalCode").length`.

Also this line *sets* the value of `#Country`.

```
$("#Country").val("Aus")
```

You want to *get* the value, and *compare* it to `"Aus"`.

```
$("#Country").val() === "Aus"
```

Try removing `minlength`, and changing your custom function.

Try this:

**EDIT:** Changed so that you have 2 validators.

One verifies that the county is Australia *and* the length of the value is at least 4.

The other verifies that the county is *not* Australia and the length of the value is at least 5.

```
$.validator.addMethod("AusZip", function(value, element) {
    var isAus = $("#Country").val() === "Aus";

    if ( isAus && value.length < 4 ) {
        return false;
    } else return true;

}, "Australian Zip Code Must Be at least 4 Digits");

$.validator.addMethod("NonAusZip", function(value, element) {
    var isNotAus = $("#Country").val() !== "Aus";

    if ( isNotAus && value.length < 5 ) {
        return false;
    } else return true;

}, "Zip Code Must Be at least 5 Digits");


$('form').validate({
    rules: {
        PostalCode: {
            required: true,
            AusZip: true,
            NonAusZip: true
        }
    }
});​
```

---

Or if you don't need a custom validation message based on the country, you could do this:

```
$.validator.addMethod("GlobalZip", function(value, element) {
    var isAus = $("#Country").val() === "Aus";

    if ( ( isAus && value.length < 4 ) || value.length < 5 ) {
        return false;
    } else return true;

}, "Zip Code is not long enough");

$('form').validate({
    rules: {
        PostalCode: {
            required: true,
            GlobalZip: true
        }
    }
});​
```

Comment: so if I remove "minlength" from the PostalCode rules will it still require a minlength of 5 for all others?

Comment: this returns an error "errorFirstWord" is not defined for some reason in console.

Comment: It should. Give it a try. This line checks for *Is Australia and less than four, OR is less than five*. `(isAus && $pCode.length < 4) || $pCode.length < 5`

Comment: @Dirty - Sorry about that. Stupid mistake on my part. Just get rid of `errorFirstWord + `  in the error string since it is not accessible outside the function.

Comment: I don't see why there is an error for "errorFirstWord" its defined locally in the function

Comment: @Dirty - That actually *is* the problem. It is defined inside the function, but is being *used* outside the function, and is not defined when the validation rule is created anyway. Looks like the message must be static.

Comment: ...I'm changing my answer to use 2 different validators. They are both based on whether or not the country is Australia. This way you can have 2 custom error messages.